# ¿Por qué esta función de AJAX me devuelve "undefined"?

Tags: php, html, ajax, formularios

estoy tratando de enviar un formulario a través de AJAX, pero al hacer un `var_dump` al `POST` de esa variable me indica el valor `undefined`. Dejo aquí el code

AJAX + HTML:

```
    function cvv_num_check(){
    jQuery.ajax({
url: "./ser.php",
data:'cvv='+$("#cvvsd").val(),
type: "POST",
success:function(data){
    $("#estadocvv").html(data);
},
error:function (){}
});
}

                        <div class="inputTarjeta">
                        <span style="float:left;" class="icon i-lock"></span><label for="codseg" style="visibility:hidden;line-height: 0px;" value="CVV"></label><input id="codseg" name="cvv" type="number" onBlur="cvv_num_check()" class="left form-control numbersOnly cvv" maxlength="4" size="4" alt="CVV" title="CVV" id="cvvsd" autocomplete="off" pattern="[0-9]{0,4}" value="">
                        <span id="estadocvv"></span>
                        </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Mira a ver que el input tiene 2 atributos id. A ver si van por ahí los tiros

Comment: Madre mía, no me había dado cuenta.
Muchas gracias @msalinas responde si quieres y te marco como correcta.
Gracias enserio jajajaj

Comment: Me alegro de que solo sea eso . La de tiempo que perdemos todos de vez en cuando por fallos de este tipo . Vale, la pongo como respuesta ahora mismo. Gracias a tí!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El `input` tiene 2 atributos `id`. Por esto te marca que el valor no está definido.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias :D